# What does the "run text" tag mean in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What does the "run text" tag mean in XAML?

It kind of just appeared in the XAML apparently put there by expression blend.  When I do a winmerge, I noticed it from a previous release of the code.

Old:

```
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="20" >^</TextBlock>
```

New:

```
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="20" ><Run Text="^"/></TextBlock>
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run

Comment: If you look at the XML that defines the new Word Docx format (open it with winzip or similar) That uses Runs, which I've understood to basically means a sequence of text (including line breaks) with consistent formatting.

Answer (score 13):

TextBlock contains an Inlines collection: [TextBlock.Inlines Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines(v=vs.110).aspx)

Run is an inline-level flow content element intended to contain a run of formatted or unformatted text: [Run Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.run)

This is an example of it's usage:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Name="myText" TextWrapping="Wrap">
    I go
    <LineBreak/>
    <Run FontStyle="Italic" Text="home"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 3):

A `TextBlock` can have more than just text as its content, it could be other controls. In your new version the content of the `TextBlock` is a [`System.Windows.Documents.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run(v=vs.110).aspx) with its [`Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property set to `^`.

This was likely done by Expression Blend because `^` could be considered a control character in some cases. By putting the text inside a `Run` it removes any ambiguity that the `^` is text and not some control character. When dealing with a complex designer it is always best to remove as much ambguitity as possible so Blend likely just did it to make it easier on its own parsing engine.

Answer (score 1):

XAML is a markup language. As such, it is *declarative*. This means that a XAML tag should never be a verb; XAML tags can only / may only / should only be nouns. If you just realize this, then you have an answer to your question: The `<Run>` tag is not telling anyone to run anything; it declares something which is a run, and since it is nested within the `<TextBlock>` tag, it follows that it most likely declares a run of text.

Of course, this realization might not be easy to arrive at, because the use of "run" as a noun is somewhat advanced english. So, here are some examples of using "run" as a noun from wiktionary.org:

- A continuous period (of time) marked by a trend; a period marked by a
  continuing trend.

  - I’m having a run of bad luck.
  - He went to Las Vegas and spent all his money over a three-day run.
- A series of tries in a game that were successful.
- A production quantity (such as in a factory).

  - Yesterday we did a run of 12,000 units.

The `<Run>` tag exists so that you can have different styling on different parts of a text message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RunText many times inside a TextBlock. For every text if you dont want to use many TextBlocks and this will be shown in runtime.